# Why isn't repository priority working in yum/dnf in Centos 8?

Tags: centos, yum, dnf

I'm trying to install a MariaDB RPM provided by MariaDB, not Centos.  Since DNF natively supports priority, that should be as simple as creating a .repo file similar to:

```
[MariaDB]
name=The MariaDB 10.4 repository
baseurl=http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos8-amd64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
priority=1
```

However, when I list available packages, I DO get packages from the newly entered MariaDB repo, but the priority=1 seems to be ignored and packages from CentOS AppStream with similar (but different case) names are over-riding it.

```
sudo yum list |grep -i mariadb-server
MariaDB-server-debuginfo.x86_64                      10.4.12-1.el8                                     MariaDB         
mariadb-server.x86_64                                3:10.3.17-1.module_el8.1.0+257+48736ea6           AppStream       
mariadb-server-galera.x86_64                         3:10.3.17-1.module_el8.1.0+257+48736ea6           AppStream       
mariadb-server-utils.x86_64                          3:10.3.17-1.module_el8.1.0+257+48736ea6           AppStream
```

However, if I disable the AppStream repo in my yum command, it works as it should (ignoring the missing dependencies from AppStream):

```
sudo yum list --disablerepo=AppStream |grep -i mariadb-server
Modular dependency problems:

 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-DBD-MySQL:4.046:8010020191114030811:073fa5fe-0.x86_64
 Problem 2: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-DBI:1.641:8010020191113222731:16b3ab4d-0.x86_64
MariaDB-server.x86_64                              10.4.12-1.el8                              MariaDB         
MariaDB-server-debuginfo.x86_64                    10.4.12-1.el8                              MariaDB
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply just a bug in DNF, possibly from the different cases used by Centos (mariadb-server) and MariaDB (MariaDB-server).

I *can* get this to work manually of course, but I want to setup puppet to install it automatically, which I can't seem to get working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case sensitivity should not matter so much here, because both packages virtually provide `mariadb-server` capability (same case).

The major reason why DNF wants to install MariaDB from AppStream is that it has a preference for modular packages. Which means, that if specific packages (names) or virtual provides are part of a *module*, and there are packages with the same names available from other repositories and they are not part of the module, then DNF will *always* want to install packages from the modular repository.

A useful command here, to find whether a specific package is part of a module is:

```
sudo dnf module provides mariadb-server
```

This finds any modules which have `mariadb-server` package.

In AppStream repo, MariaDB packages are with the `mariadb` module.

By disabling the AppStream we put a blind fold on DNF so it doesn't see what it likes. But the better way is to teach it to like non-modular packages by adding `module_hotfixes=1` to the repository of interest, e.g.:

```
[MariaDB]
name=The MariaDB 10.4 repository
baseurl=http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos8-amd64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
priority=1
module_hotfixes=1
```

Note that priority config should be retained, because technically `3:10.3.17` (higher `Epoch: 3`) version still wins over `10.4.12` (`Epoch: none`, same as `0:10.4.12`).

Comment: Thanks.  This works perfectly.  I had a suspicion the problem had something to do with modules, but IIUC modules are new in DNF, so this is the first time I've encountered them.